# Advanced search - combine "expressions"?

Tags: support, search

Is it doesn't work - or i'm too stupid for ...

Put this into search `user:me is:answer score:0` and you'll get all your zero score answers.

It is possible to use multiple IDs and apply **simple** filters `user:A user:B is:question ...`, but how to search for my answers for a specific user?

Some like `user:me is:answer <author>:<userid>` or `user:me is:answer user:ID is:question` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be wrong on this, but I think the search functions work with `AND` without combining criteria. I mean something like `user:me is:answer user:ID is:question` will translate into something like `user = me and is_answer = true and user = ID and is_question = true`. Which will always return nothing because `user = me` and `user = id` exclude each other.
But I think you can achieve what you want here: https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/queries.
First look if something similar to what you need already exists. If not, try to build one query.